# How to get all pages of public folder in express.js and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am New to node.js and nginx. I created one node.js application using express.js structure. I hosted that applictation in nginx for https. And crated one domain ap.local.in. Now i run project with https://ap.local.in i get first page of views folder.Now i want get https://ap.local.in/event when i run https://ap.local.in/event i got **404 Not found**
How to get all pages of views folder.Is it possible?
 Please help me!
my nginx.conf file is

> 

```
 server {
  listen        80;
  listen        [::]:80;
  server_name   ap.local.in;
  root          /www/html;



   location / {
      proxy_pass "http://www.ap.local.in:8080";


  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how i think you code should look like:

```js
var event = require('./routes/eventRoute');
var app = express(); app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use('/event', event)
```

Comment: i am using .jade extension

Comment: i did same way but i got 404 error. I think that is problem in nginx .conf file